# How to run multiple functions simultaneously and periodically within a while loop

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop, concurrency

In Python, I am trying to run two functions in a while loop such that one function runs continuously while another runs periodically within the same while loop, without stopping the continuous function from being run.
For Example:

```
while True:
    function_runs_continiously()
    function_runs_every_minute()
```

Comment: Look into threads or async features.

Comment: Why within the same loop? The continuous function could be in another thread. Is there any one to one correspondence between these two?

Comment: What does "runs continuously" mean? Why are you starting them within a loop? Please expand your example to show an example for `function_runs_continuously()` and an example for `function_runs_every_minute()`.

Answer (score 2):

like Michael suggested you should use threads

something like:

```
import threading
import time

x = threading.Thread(target=function_runs_continiously, args=(), daemon=True)
x.start()
while True:
  function_runs_every_minute()
  time.sleep(60)
```

or use another thread for function_runs_every_minute.
But be aware of race conditions with threads, if you use the same data in both functions.

Comment: awesome first answer. welcome to stack overflow!

Answer (score 1):

Going off of [blablup's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74035056/13376511), you will also need to use locks if you want to safely access global variables (which you probably want to do). This should prevent a race condition. Here's an example:

```
import threading
import time


counter = 0
counter_lock = threading.Lock()


def function_runs_continiously():
    global counter
    with counter_lock:
        counter += 1


def wrapper_func():
    while True:
        function_runs_continiously()


def function_runs_every_minute():
    global counter
    with counter_lock:
        counter += 10
        print(counter)


x = threading.Thread(target=wrapper_func, args=(), daemon=True)
x.start()
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    function_runs_every_minute()
```